# Syntax highlighting in SEDE editor fails past 5000 characters on a line

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, syntax-highlighting

If you open [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/258843/sede-syntax-highlighting-bug) and fork it (so it opens in the SEDE editor), and then scroll about two-thirds of the way to the right, you see that syntax highlighting vanishes. It appears to vanish past 5000 characters on a line, like so:

[image]

This is frighteningly trivial, and I don't expect that anyone will care enough to fix this, but I thought you might like to know.

Comment: Interesting observation... Of course, you should bring your queries on over to Code Review, and we'll tell you to make your lines shorter. Also, I see in your query history that you are building queries 'across sites'. Your code assumes there is no ;linkage', but there is. I can help you on building some queries like that, e.g. [This query correlates user over multiple sites](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/204453/xsite-user-voting?UserId=31503)

Comment: @rolfl lol sure would've been nice if I noticed the `Users.AccountId` column. That's super-helpful, thanks!

Comment: I'd expect _something_ to break when you hit 5k characters per line. Or way sooner, actually.

Comment: I would have thought 4096 would be the actual number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce this locally, so I'm going to assume that I've preemptively [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) this by upgrading the relevant CodeMirror code, which is one of a few changes that are still pending deployment to the public SEDE instance.